# Use of .NET 4 SmtpClient to send multiple emails in one batch (Send vs SendAsync)

Tags: .net, smtpclient

I have written a console app that reads a queue of messages in a table and sends them as email  to multiple recipients. A typical usage scenario would be to send 2000 emails in one go, each to a different email address with a subtly different mail body (mail merged name, address etc.)

The app works and seems to process 2000 mails in around a minute and a half. The approach I've used is really simple (I've taken out try..catch blocks for brevity) :

```
using (var mailBot = new SmtpClient())
{
    foreach (var mail in dataContext.Mails
                                        .Where(item => !item.IsSent)
                                        .OrderBy(item => item.MailId)
                                        .ToList())
    {
        mailBot.Send(new MailMessage(mail.MailFrom, mail.MailTo, mail.Subject, mail.Message));
        mail.IsSent = true;
        dataContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Now, my question is, how can I speed up the operation of this app? I feel like this serial approach might be improved on by using `SmtpClient.SendAsync()` instead, but I'm concerned that I have no control on how many threads would get created, and I would still need the app to hang around for the result of sending, because I need to flag whether the mail was sent successfully or not. Also, I figure the receiving SMTP server can only process a certain number of concurrent requests.

So am I fooling myself in thinking that a multi-threaded solution could speed up mail delivery and allow the app to exit earlier?

Comment: Here are the guidelines of how gmail handles bulk senders http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=81126

Comment: Note that there is very high risk of rejection of your email from antispam filters. If 2+ of email addresses are on the same mail server, it can deny them as spam.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Parallel.ForEach` as illustrated [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd7c2e/send-bulk-mails-at-faster-rate/).